# All nameservers failed to answer UDP port 53 Google cloud functions python 3.7 atlas mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, google-cloud-functions, mongodb-atlas

i can connect locally to my mongodb server with the address 0.0.0.0/0. However, when I deploy my code to the cloud I get the error deploy to google cloud function.

google cloud function with python 3.7 (beta)
atlas mongo db
python lib:
-pymongo
-dnspython

`Error: function crashed. Details:
All nameservers failed to answer the query _mongodb._tcp.**-***.gcp.mongodb.net. IN SRV: Server ***.***.***.*** UDP port 53 answered SERVFAIL`

`Traceback (most recent call last): File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/uri_parser.py", line 287, in _get_dns_srv_hosts results = resolver.query('_mongodb._tcp.' + hostname, 'SRV') File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dns/resolver.py", line 1132, in query raise_on_no_answer, source_port) File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dns/resolver.py", line 947, in query raise NoNameservers(request=request, errors=errors) dns.resolver.NoNameservers: All nameservers failed to answer the query _mongodb._tcp.**mymongodb**-r091o.gcp.mongodb.net. IN SRV: Server ***.***.***.*** UDP port 53`

Comment: I would like to rephrase your question like this: "I can connect locally to my mongo db server with the address 0.0.0.0/0. However, when I deploy my code to the cloud I get the error: ..."

Comment: I have no experience in mongo db, but am trying to clarify the problem for others. I'm not certain that I am helping...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

finally after stuck 2 day, goblok banget semaleman

just change connection 
from

> SRV connection string (3.6+ driver)

to

> Standard connection string (3.4+ driver)

`mongodb://<USERNAME>:<PASSWORD>@<DATABASE>-shard-00-00-r091o.gcp.mongodb.net:27017,<COLLECTION>-shard-00-01-r091o.gcp.mongodb.net:27017,<COLLECTION>-shard-00-02-r091o.gcp.mongodb.net:27017/test?ssl=true&replicaSet=<COLLECTION>-shard-0&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true`

or you can see your connection string in atlas mongodb.

idk why **can`t connect with srv connection string** in google cloud functions, maybe not suppot now, or just misconfiguration.

Comment: Actually, I think I have a solution. It's possible to use the `mongodb+srv://` URI by installing [`dnspython`](https://pypi.org/project/dnspython); see [the docs](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html).

Comment: and restart the kernel after installing dnspython

Answer (score 3):

This might help somone, I've struggled with this error on Windows when I tried to connect to MongoDB with the `mongodb+srv://` syntax, it worked fine if I try it through WSL or on a Linux machine.

> From https://forum.omz-software.com/topic/6751/pymongo-errors-configurationerror-resolver-configuration-could-not-be-read-or-specified-no-nameservers/4

```py
import dns.resolver
dns.resolver.default_resolver=dns.resolver.Resolver(configure=False)
dns.resolver.default_resolver.nameservers=['8.8.8.8'] # this is a google public dns server,  use whatever dns server you like here
# as a test, dns.resolver.query('www.google.com') should return an answer, not an exception
```

Comment: No clue why that actually helped me, but I am very thankful for your answer!

Answer (score 2):

Most of the time the error occurs when your network isn't configured with 8.8.8.8 DNS Adress.

Type the following command on **command prompt** to verify

> `ipconfig /all`

check your IP configuration & in the config you should see the following

```
DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 8.8.8.8  
                                    8.8.4.4
```

if not you should configure your network using `8.8.8.8` as primary DNS and `8.8.4.4` as secondary.

OR

May be you are using a VPN or private DNS.In that case contact you service provider for the assistance.

Comment: I solved the same issue by loggin into my router & configuring DNS.

Comment: I can't believe no one liked this answer. I had this problem deploying a remote server and you saved my afternoon.